# find() method not working for Ember Data Model

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, model, ember-data, routes

I am new to EmberJs and inside my Route method, Im returning the Module Model which has fixture data. Here is the code for the Route:

```
App.ModulesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return App.Module.find();
  }         
});
```

Here is the code for my model and DS.Store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Module = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

But I'm getting an error saying 'has no 'find' method:

Am I missing something? I just got the latest ember-data file too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old syntes for finding records, lets rewrite your code.

```
App.ModulesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return this.store.find('module');
  }         
});
```

And if you want to find a specific Module, you can provide a id like this.

```
App.ModulesShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
   return this.store.find('module', params.module_id);
  }         
});
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting the followingerror:Error while loading route: undefined

Comment: Sounds like you have issues with your router, i can recommend the emberjs inspector, to see if your routes are correct. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi

Comment: 'Module' should be lower cased.